# How to check if CString contains CarriageReturn + Line Feed \r\n

Tags: c++, mfc

Ciao

I am new with visual c++ 6

If i have a CString that contains a multiline string, a string that contains "\r\n"
how can i check if this string contains "\r\n"??? how can i check if is a multiline?

The follow code doesn't work; CString::Find doesn't work, return always -1

```
CString myString;
.......
bool found = false;
if( myString.Find(_T("\r\n")) != -1)   
  found = true;
......
```

Can someone help me??

Comment: Wait, did you say Visual C++ 6?

Comment: Yes, Visual C++ 6!!! I know that is obsolete, but i need to work with this

Comment: `CString::Find` should work. Are you sure the string actually contains `"\r\n"`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you, but first things first. Are you sure the multiline string contains `\r\n` pairs? When reading from a text file, line ends are translated to `\n`.

Comment: I'm almost sure because code below works correctly

CString s = str;
while (!s.IsEmpty())
{
  CString one_line = s.SpanExcluding( _T("\r\n"));
  TRACE( "%s\n", one_line);
  s = s.Right( s.GetLength() - one_line.GetLength());
  s.TrimLeft( _T("\r\n"));
}

Comment: `SpanExcluding` looks for *one* of the characters given, not all of them.

Comment: Loop over the string and print out the numerical values of the chars. Does it say 13 and 10 or just 10 for line ends?

Comment: What interjay said. In addition, `TrimLeft` trims any of the characters given, not the literal string, so the result would be the same regardless if your original contained `\r\n` or `\r` or any combination.

Comment: CString s = str;  s.Replace("\r\n","\n"); s.Replace("\r","\n"); s.Replace("\n","\r\n");  int nPos = s.Find("\r\n");

Comment: Ciao
You excuse me 2 time!!!! I made an error: i checked the file with a exadecimal editor and i discovered that the multiline string doesn't contains the couple "\r\n" 0D 0A but only the Line Feed "\n" 0A, then CString::Find work correctly!!! Your indications have been helpful!!! you excuse me again!!

Comment: @peppemath No need to apologise. As long we helped you realise what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your content probably does not have `\r\n`.

I tried a sample, it worked:

```
  CString myString;

   myString ="Today is a good day \r\n Tomorrow too";

   bool found = false;
   if( myString.Find(_T("\r\n")) != -1)   
      found = true;
```